# How interrupt a websocket (using boost beast) from another thread?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast

I 'm using boost beast 1.74.0.  in another thread i try close the websocket but the code is broken at "acceptor.accept(socket, endpoint)" and i receive "Signal: SIG32 (Real-time event 32)" after call close.

Part from code to listen connection, What i need change to interrupt the accept correctly the service?

```
...
 _acceptor = &acceptor;
 _keepAlive = true;
 while (_keepAlive) {
            tcp::socket socket{ioc};
            // Block until we get a connection
            acceptor.accept(socket, endpoint);

            // Launch the session, transferring ownership of the socket
            std::thread(
                    &WebSocketServer::doSession,
                    std::move(socket),
                    this,
                    this,
                    getHeaderServer()
            ).detach();
        }
```

close function call by another thread

```
void WebSocketServer::close() {
    if (_acceptor != nullptr) this->close();
    _keepAlive = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`glibc` uses SIG32 to signal the cancellation of threads created using the pthread library. Are you trying to use `pthread_kill`?

If not, you may be witnessing that only because you are running it under GDB. Which should be fixable by telling GDB to ignore that:

```
handle SIG32 nostop noprint
```

Finally to the original question:

- there's interupption points in Boost Thread. They could help you **iff** you can switch to Boost Thread `boost::thread` instead of `std::thread`. Also, you have to change the thread's code to actually check for interruptions: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption
- Since it actually sounds like you want to terminate the accept loop, why not "simply" cancel the acceptor? I'm not entirely sure this works with synchronous operations, but you could of course easily use an async accept.

  > Take care to synchronize access to the acceptor object itself. This means either run `cancel` on the same thread doing `async_accept` or from the same `strand`. By this point it surely sounds like it's easier to just do the whole thing asynchronously.